# How do I migrate my Aperture library from my primary HDD to an external drive?

Tags: snow-leopard, aperture

I have about 53GB of photos in my Aperture library which is stored on my internal HDD. I would like to move this library onto an external hard disk and continue to use Aperture without any loss of images, etc.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, here are the steps:

- Connect your external disk
- Open Finder and go to `<your home folder>/Pictures`
- move the Aperture Library.aplibrary file to a location on your new disk
- Open Aperture and go to preferences ( from menu or by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> )
- On the General tab, change the location of the library to where you copied the Aperture Library.aplibrary file

That's it, the library is now on your external drive.

Comment: ALso if you just double-click on the Aperture library from the new drive, it will open Aperture using that library and keep doing so until it cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Or before opening Aperture, hold down the Option/Alt key then click o Aperture to open. Aperture will ask you where your library is, then you can point it to your external drive.